# Couldn't find Suscription without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application with users using devise for authentication, in the user model I have added in the database a column called admin with false value by default. that way I have managed to have access as administrator to certain parts of the application.
I have a subscription model and each user when authenticated gets a free value by default. what I want to achieve is that the admin user in your user list can be able to switch from free to premium. this is the code i have and i can't get it to work.

**Users Model:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  
  #Validaciones
  validates :nombre, :apellido, presence: true
  devise :database_authenticatable, :validatable, password_length: 8..128
  

  #Relaciones
  has_many :patients, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :suscription, dependent: :destroy
  
 
 
  #Creación de perfil
  after_create :set_profile
  def set_profile
       self.profile = Profile.create()  
  end      
  
  #Creación de suscripcion
  after_create :set_suscription
  def set_suscription
       self.suscription = Suscription.create()  
  end  

end
```

**Suscription Model:**

```
class Suscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  enum status: {
    free:     0,
    premium:  1
  }
end
```

**Users controllers:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @pagy, @users = pagy(User.order(created_at: :asc), items:12)
    end
    
    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
    
    
    
end
```

**Suscriptios controller:**

```
class SuscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_suscription
  
  def show
    
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @suscription = Suscription.find(params[:id]).update_params
    redirect_to profile_path
    flash[:notice] = "La suscripción ha sido actualizada"
  end

  private
  def set_suscription
    @suscription = (current_user.suscription ||= Suscription.create)
  end

  def suscription_params
    params.require(:suscription).permit(:status)
  end
end
```

**Route:**
#UPDATE PREMIUM

```
patch "suscriptions", to:"suscriptions#update", as: "user_premium"
```

**View (Link):**

```
<%= link_to 'Update', user_premium_path ,method: :patch %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

subscriptions_controller.rb

```
def update
  @suscription = Suscription.find(params[:id]).update(subscription_params)
  redirect_to profile_path
  flash[:notice] = "La suscripción ha sido actualizada"
end
```

view

```
<%= link_to 'Update', user_premium_path(id: @subscription.id, status: "premium"), method: :patch %>
```

One other thing that is not needed, but normally I would see something like this in a controller:

```
private

  def set_suscription
    @suscription = Suscription.find(params[:id])
  end
```

which then makes your update method look like this:

```
def update
  @subscription.update(subscription_params)
  redirect_to profile_path
  flash[:notice] = "La suscripción ha sido actualizada"
end
```

This is all assuming you are simply trying to update the subscription from free to premium with your link_to.  I wouldn't recommend doing anything like this, because what if someone accidentally marks this?  They can no longer go back to a free subscription.  Maybe have a modal open that is routed to subscription edit with a drop down to select the status would be better?

Comment: Yes, I think it is not the best way, but I want to test to see if the admin user can update the status.
anyway the view gives me this error:
undefined method `id 'for nil: NilClass

Comment: no worries.  Yes, I'm assuming you have access to the subscription in the view.  You just need to pass the subscription ID in your link_to.  If you post your whole view I can help you with the link_to.  Just not sure what you are looping over. If it's users, then you can easily access the subscription ID.

Comment: my view only contains the link_to:
<% = link_to 'Update', user_premium_path, method:: patch%>

which I corrected it with the recommendation that you suggested to me

Comment: Yes, I can access the subscription id, I stay like this but the error I have is in the controller.
<% = link_to 'Update', user_premium_path (id: @ user.suscription.id, status: "premium"), method:: patch%>

here I get this error: param is missing or the value is empty: subscription
def suscription_params
     params.require (: subscription) .permit (: status)
   end